# How to get members from a Custom AD role with MS Graph Powershell

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-powershell, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to get the members from a custom role created in the portal with MS Powershell Graph. This custom role is active and has members assigned.

I can't get a DirectoryRoleId from the custom role, if it even exists, to run the Get-MgDirectoryRoleMember.

I figured out the following:

- `Get-MgDirectoryRole` retrieved all active roles, but no custom roles.
- `Get-MgDirectoryRoleTemplate` Retrieved all roles including those that are not activated, but no custom roles. Total number roles 98.
- `Get-MgRoleManagementDirectoryRoleDefinition` Alle roles including those that are not activated, but now including my custom role! Total number roles 99.

Unfortunately I don't get a DirectoryRoleId this way so I can't use it with `Get-MgDirectoryRoleMember -DirectoryRoleId '<id>'`. This cmdlet works fine with the default roles.

Am I missing another cmdlet to extract members of custom roles via MS Graph PowerShell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I created one **custom** directory role named *"Directory Admininistrator"* with below ID and permissions:

[image]

Now, I added **2 active** role assignments(users) for this custom role like this:

[image]

I ran below MS Graph Powershell commands to get `DirectoryRoleId` from the custom directory role:

```
Connect-MgGraph
Get-MgRoleManagementDirectoryRoleDefinition -Filter "(displayName eq 'Directory Admininistrator')"
```

**Response:**
[image]

When I tried to get members of this **custom role** with below script, I got error like this:

```
# Get the role definition for your custom role
$roleDefinition = Get-MgRoleManagementDirectoryRoleDefinition -Filter "(displayName eq 'Directory Admininistrator')"

# Get the members of your custom role
$roleMembers = Get-MgDirectoryRoleMember -DirectoryRoleId $roleDefinition.Id

# Display the results
$roleMembers
```

**Response:**

[image]

> AFAIK, listing members from a custom Azure AD role with Powershell is **currently in Preview** state that may cause error. Check this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/view-assignments#powershell:%7E:text=custom%20roles%20%28currently%20in%20Preview%29).

Alternatively, you can use Azure AD Powershell commands to list **active role assignments** of custom directory role.

I ran below commands to get `DirectoryRoleId` from the custom directory role:

```
Connect-AzureAD
Get-AzureADMSRoleDefinition -Filter "displayName eq 'Directory Admininistrator'"
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I tried to get members of this **custom role** with below script, I got response with `user IDs` assigned to that role successfully like below:

```
# Get the role definition for your custom role
$roleDefinition = Get-AzureADMSRoleDefinition -Filter "displayName eq 'Directory Admininistrator'"

# Get the members of your custom role
$roleMembers = Get-AzureADMSRoleAssignment -Filter "roleDefinitionId eq '$($role.Id)'"

# Display the results
$roleMembers
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to avoid Azure AD powershell, but for now this will work. Thank you for your time!